# How to add login form in a vuetify spa outside of a sidebar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vuetify.js

I am new in spa routing world. I am using vuejs in the frontend and laravel in the backend and using the vuetify component framework.

My application root is `{domain}/app`. The route definition in the backend:

```
Route::get('app', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

And here is a glimpse of how the `index.blade.php` looks:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<v-app id="inspire">
<v-navigation-drawer
v-model="drawer"
fixed
app
>
  <!-- Some other components -->
  <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
          <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
  </v-content>
</v-navigation-drawer>
@endsection
```

But the situation gets worse when I need entirely a new page, such as the login page. I can't put it inside the navigation drawer, it's not a child of the `v-app` but itself is another `v-app`. Here is how my `Login.vue` looks like:

```
<v-app id="inspire">
      <v-content>
        <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <!-- login form -->
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
</v-app>
```

How can I set up routes in such a way so that login route will not be nested into the `v-app` (populated by `router-view`) but itself will be another `v-app`?

Here is my current setup (`routes.js`):

```
let routes = [
    { path: '/', component: require('./views/Home') },
    { path: '/login', component: require('./views/auth/Login') },
    { path: '/order', component: require('./views/order/List') },
    //... other routes ...
]
```

Comment: Why does your login route need to be inside of its own Vue application?

Comment: @NiallGMC because it's a separate page. It cannot be part of the dashboard/home, right? Because then it would look like that the login page has a navigation drawer.

Comment: if you ever want to see it done in a real project there is one here https://github.com/ClintOxx/vuetify-admin-dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**App.vue** (root)

```
<template>
   <main>
      <transition mode="out-in">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </transition>
   </main>
</template>
```

In **app.js** [configure](https://011.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html) the layout of `#app`

```
import AppLayout from './components/App.vue'

new Vue(
  Vue.util.extend(
     { router, store },   // router.js, store.js (if using module or Vuex)
     AppLayout
  )  
).$mount('#app')
```

**Home.vue** (main page)

```
<template>
   <v-app id="home">

     //...any contents here like navbars

      <v-content>
        <transition mode="out-in">
           <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
     </v-content>

   </v-app>
</template>
```

**Dashboard.vue** (with navigation-drawer)

```
<template>
   <v-app id="dashboard">

     <v-navigation-drawer app>
          ...
     </v-navigation-drawer>

     //...any contents here

     <v-content>
        <transition mode="out-in">
           <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
     </v-content>

   </v-app>
</template>
```

**routes.js**

```
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import Panel from './components/Panel'

export const routes = [
 {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/dashboard/panel',
            component: Panel
        }
    ]
 }
]
```